# Access Denied on Static Website using Google Platform Bucket

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am creating a bucket and adding an index.html file to the bucket through my node.js API. however, when I try to access the website it gives me this error.

```
AccessDeniedAccess denied.
```

I have done some research and found [this article](http://tekhoow.blogspot.com/2015/12/soving-accessdenied-on-google-cloud.html) about running terminal codes to update the security preferences on the Google Cloud Bucket. However, the nature of my app prevents me from manually doing this through the terminal each time a bucket is created.

How would I get this accomplished automatically for each bucket created?

Here is my Node.Js code for creating my bucket.

```
exports.createDefaultBucket = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
cors(req, res, () => {

    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    var bucketName = req.body.siteName;

    var defaultIndex = '';
    var defaultCss   = '';

    if(!bucketName) {
        res.send('Bucket name is required!');
    } else {
        storage.createBucket(bucketName).then(() => {
            storage.bucket(bucketName).makePublic().then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(defaultIndex).then(() => {
                    //storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(defaultCss).then(() => {
                        res.send(bucketName+' was created, made public, has default index file and index location is set!');
                    //})
                })
            }).catch(err => {
                res.send(err);
            })
        }).catch(err => {
            res.send(err);
        });
    }

});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain what makePublic does exactly, but it might not be updating the defaultObjectAcl.  Based on the documentation on makePublic it looks like you may need to include the option to also update the files.. but that might only update the existing files.

https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.4.x/Bucket#makePublic

```
//-
// Make the bucket and its contents publicly readable.
//-
var opts = {
  includeFiles: true
};

bucket.makePublic(opts, function(err, files) {
  // `err`:
  //    The first error to occur, otherwise null.
  //
  // `files`:
  //    Array of files successfully made public in the bucket.
});
```

I would recommend using IAM instead.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles
https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.4.x/Bucket#iam

```
bucket.iam
  .getPolicy()
  .then(results => {
    const policy = results[0];

    // Adds the new roles to the bucket's IAM policy
    policy.bindings.push({
      // storage.objectViewers role grants buckets.list and objects.get
      role: 'roles/storage.objectViewers',
      members: 'allUsers',
    });

    // Updates the bucket's IAM policy
    return bucket.iam.setPolicy(policy);
  })
```